# MySql EXPLAIN efficiencies

Tags: mysql, explain

I'm trying to use `EXPLAIN` to take a closer look at my queries and see how they're running, and so far, the largest `id` created in an `EXPLAIN`has been 7, but it was lengthy query with a lot going on. I just made another query with a structure similar to below and `EXPLAIN` gave me an `id` maximum of 13. From what I know about `EXPLAIN` is it generally means the query is less efficient/runs longer the higher an id `EXPLAIN` gives, but is this a relative rule or are there some sort of boundaries? Like is a query running with a max of 2 id's seen as very efficient and a query with a max id of 13 seen as very unefficient, or is it just 2 is more efficient than 13? Of course there's the third option of id number having no correlation to efficiency. 
ID 13 Query:

```
select if(cond1, subquery, if(cond2, subquery(subsubquery),
subquery(subsubquery))) as colA, if(cond1, subquery(subsubquery), if(cond2,
subquery(subsubquery), subquery(subsubquery))) as colB from TableA join
TableB on X group by y order by z desc
```

Comment: I suspect that this is too broad to answer succinctly -but that query looks horrendous!!!!

Comment: I was more looking for a general answer, which Uueerdo sufficed to do, just to guide my thinking more so. Oh I am very aware at how terrible that looks and I'm definitely revisiting it to hopefully cut down at least the amount of subqueries, if not the if statements as well

Comment: those sorts of queries *can* be symptomatic of poor schema design, and if there are no aggregating functions at the top level, then (performance advantages aside), there should be no group by clause either.

Comment: It's for work and I don't have much control over the database structure, if I did that query could condensed into a single query with some sum and count functions thrown in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never really heard of the id number correlating to efficiency. Unless I am mistaken, it is just little more than the number of tables (and derived tables) that end up being involved in processing the query.

Joining to a huge table once might make for less/lower id; joining to temp tables that are duplicate (since you can't use them twice in one query) but a miniscule relevant fraction of that huge table (and better/more appropriately indexed) numerous times is sure to increase the id count, but may run much more quickly and efficiently... even factoring in the cost of the preceding queries that were needed to generate those temp tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had thought I had heard max id correlated to efficiency, but glad to hear some clarification on it

Comment: It might be a decent general/vague guideline to go by with simple queries; but when trying to get more complicated results, there are just to many optimization tricks that would increase the id it to make it a reliable metric.

Comment: So sounds like a relative guide to consider and possibly raise concern about run time, but to not use as a sole reason to be concerned about run time and efficiency